# systemd : how to get last n process status change

Tags: systemd

Does systemd maintain process state change somewhere ? If so how can I get last n process state change

Even if not all status can I get information corresponds to process restart . Information like when and why

For example

```
$systemd-processBootHistory 
process-name    boot-time   signal 
process1         03mins        11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Systemd doesn't maintain process state change.